# Android Studio / Gradle libraries with interdependancies in Bitbucket

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, bitbucket

I have a couple of Android Studio libraries that I have placed in two private repositories on Bitbucket.

Both libraries actualy have dependancies from each other.

How can I accomplish that they can "see"/import each other ?

I cannot seem to get it working in the gradle files themselves, as in there is no support for bitbucket repositories.
I did find this project : 
https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-repositories-plugin

But onfortunately it only supports non-private repositories, thus it does not work for us.

Comment: If you have both projects downloaded, add them to your `build.gradle` like `compile project('ProjA') and `compile project('ProjB')`.

Comment: I actually dont download them, to be honest I'd like to import them a la Maven repositiry within gradle...

Comment: You could upload them to jcenter and then add them your dependencies. I am not sure "downloading from git into android studio" exists or maybe that a plugin can do it for you.